# Does Gmail use setInterval() or setTimeOut() to do periodical refresh?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, architecture, gmail

I guess they use these two functions to make an `Ajax` call to their server but I am not sure.  How do they do that?

Thank you.

Comment: why do people vote this question down?  is this to easy?

Comment: Jay1997, have you looked at the source code?

Comment: @epascarello all the javascript code is obfuscated, how can I do that?

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ or https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/

Comment: their variables are all obfuscated.  Also, if they use some server-side technology such as Comet, looking at Comet won't help a lot, will it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to reverse-engineer Gmail, but most likely they are using some form of [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (reverse AJAX).

With this approach information is available instantly without any delay and additional network traffic.

Comment: Comet-like techniques are generally called server-push.