# Can I use socket.io with twisted.web?

Tags: python, ajax, socket.io, twisted, twisted.web

I'm writing a web application using Python's `twisted.web` on the server side.

On the frontend side I would like to use `Ajax` for displaying real time updates of events which are happening in the server.

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710759/how-do-websites-instantly-update-their-content-using-ajax) [are](http://coder1.com/articles/twisted-long-polling-jsonp) [lots](http://ajaxian.com/archives/prototype-and-jquery-a-code-comparison) of information out there on how this can be done, so I realized I need to pick [a](http://jquery.com/) [javascript](http://www.prototypejs.org/) [library](http://socket.io/) that would make my life easier.

`socket.io` seems to be a good choice since it supports several browsers and transport mechanisms, but by reading their examples it seems it can only work with `node.js`?

So, does anyone know if it's possible to use `socket.io` with `twisted.web`?
If so, any links for a good example/tutorial would be also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something server side to integrate with the socket.io script on the client side. The servers that I know that are written in Python and do this all use Tornado. You could look at an implementation like, Tornadio (https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio) and see what methods and classes they used to hook Tornadio and Tornado together. This would give you a pretty good idea of how to integrate it with your twisted.web server.

We've just switched away from socket.io to [sockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) (which is also compatible with Tornado) and have seen large performance improvements.

Answer (score 3):

You could try https://github.com/DesertBus/sockjs-twisted or if you need SocketIO for a specific reason, it wouldn't be difficult to port [TornadIO2](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2) to [Cyclone](http://cyclone.io/). You might find interesting [this issue](https://github.com/fiorix/cyclone/issues/82).